# Generate stars according to the model variable

Tags: angular, typescript

I am developing a rating star component which displays stars based on the result got from the database.

i have a variable in app.ts as follows,

```
this.rating = 4;
```

And my HTML is as follows,

```
 <div class="rating-star-group pull-right">
     <i class="zmdi zmdi-star"></i>
     <i class="zmdi zmdi-star"></i>
     <i class="zmdi zmdi-star"></i>
     <i class="zmdi zmdi-star"></i>
     <i class="zmdi zmdi-star-outline"></i>
 </div>
```

should i add a ng-if and check for the variable to display the class or is there a better way to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using `ng-bootstrap` plugin which is Angular 2 wrapper over bootstrap 4.(Same as that of `ui-bootstrap`)

That has [**`ngb-rating`**](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/rating) which has great implementation of all cases.

```
<ngb-rating [(rate)]="currentRate"></ngb-rating>
```

Comment: i do not want to use any plugin

Comment: @Sajeetharan then build your own, take a look at [this](https://embed.plnkr.co/OZsBykh76cbmkE4UdEeQ/)